# Should it be 1.5K instead of 1.5°C?

Tags: temperature, units, si-units, unit-conversion

So everyone talks about how global warming should be limitted to 1.5°C. However, in my understanding the following conversion should be used:
$${\displaystyle \left\{t\right\}_{\mathrm {^{\circ }C} }=\left\{T\right\}_{\mathrm {K} }-273{.}15},$$
so 1.5°C would be 274.65K, wouldn't it? Obviously, no one wants a global warming of 274.65K, so shouldn't we rather talk about a warming of 1.5K instead of 1.5°C?

Comment: they mean change in temperature.

Comment: @LordlyAmigo yes, but shouldn't change in temperature (generally) be given in Kelvin?

Comment: change in kelvin or Celsius doesnt make any differencè like if you say it ``` It was 1°C more than freezing point of ice ``` or you say ```  It was 1K more than freezing point of water ``` both convey same thing i.e. 274.15K or 1°C

Comment: Not when you're trying to explain things to people who think a 1/3lbs burger is smaller than a quarter pounder.

Comment: A Professor at University made a joke in a lecture that very few in the audience seemed to get "The temperature of the interior of the Sun is about 15 million degrees (but I forget whether that's Celsius or Kelvin)..."

Comment: @DKNguyen, indeed, and those people who are SO mathematically illiterate that they don't know that 1/3 is larger than 1/4 still vote.  If that group becomes the majority, we are all DOOMED!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have brought up a constant problem in referring to temperatures and temperature differences.

The problem is that they are referred to in the same way! And unfortunately, the problem persists even when one used Kelvin.

In one sense, $100$ K, or $100 ^{\circ }C$ or $100 ^{\circ }F$ refer to a place on the temperature  scale (three different places, of course)

On the other hand, if you need to refer to increasing the temperature of some solution from, say$45 ^{\circ }C$ to $85 ^{\circ }C$, you would refer to raising the temperature by $40 ^{\circ }C$

In my career of teaching basic physics, I tried to distinguish by using. say $18 ^{\circ }C$ for the temperature. and $18 \text { C degrees}$ for the temperature difference.

There is a similar problem in talking about positions and distances on US Interstate highways, where Mile $80$ is only $8$ miles from Mile $72$.

There have been instances of translation errors in cookbooks causing poorly cooked food.

Some circumstances lead the chef/author to recommend increasing the cooking temperature by $25 ^{\circ }C$ and the translation comes out to increase the temp by $77 ^{\circ }F$, instead of the correct $45 ^{\circ }F$

Some unit conversion apps have separate sections: one for converting temperatures and one for converting temperature differences

Answer (score 8):

Temperature differences are the same in kelvin and degrees celsius:

\begin{align}
\{\Delta T\}_{K} &= \{T_2\}_{K} - \{T_1\}_{K}\\ &=  \{T_2\}_{^{\circ}C} + 273\, - \left(\{T_1\}_{^{\circ}C} + 273\,\right)\\
&= \{T_2\}_{^{\circ}C}- \{T_1\}_{^{\circ}C}\\
&= \{\Delta T\}_{^{\circ}C}
\end{align}